# imperfective vs perfective in English (I was doing/ I did)?

Tags: past-simple, present-continuous, past-continuous

I tend to use the continuous form a lot for situations that happened in the near past as it brings my mind closer to the actual action that was performed. I'm still not sure if this is grammatically acceptable.

For instance in this sentence:

> Person A comes home after work and asks Person B: What did you do
>   today?
>
> Person B answers: I was lying in bed all day.

In this example, if Person B answered 'I've been lying in bed all day',to me, it suggests that the person is still lying in bed and intends on continuing to do so. The simple past 'I lay in bed all day' sounds like it was a moment in the far past whereas 'I was lying in bed all day' sounds like it's closer to the present and it also communicates annoyance.

Another example would be:

> Person A asks: Where were you?
>
> Person B answers:  I was cleaning the car, why?

Those are situations I'd image myself answering exactly like that and I can't let go of that 'habit'.

Is there a grammatical exception or is this really just a bad habit of mine?

Comment: *The simple past 'I lay in bed all day' sounds like it was a moment in the far past* - it doesn't imply that to this English speaker.  English doesn't really have different tenses for "far past" vs. "near past"; the simple past can be used for any action that is completed, no matter how recent.  That said, it's not wrong to say "I was lying" or "I was cleaning"!

Comment: @standgon Thank you for the quick reply! To confirm what you just said: If I use the continuous form for something that happened in the past without something that happened at the same time, which is the conventional rule, (e.g. I was cleaning the car when Mom came home) it's accepted?

Comment: Yes, you can simply say "I was lying in bed" or "I was cleaning the car."  I think we use that a lot when the time is implied by a question or another sentence, like "What were you doing all day?" or "I remember when I heard that Frederick had died."

Comment: Personally, for the first one, I'd use past tense because the action has ended (I'm assuming), i.e., "I laid in bed all day." I would only use the past progressive if the action stops at the time of asking, e.g., "I was lying in bed all day until (you asked) just now."

Comment: For the second one, I would be fine with the past progressive as you have used it here for exactly the same reason as I have stated above: The action was true up to the current moment and time of asking.